# Vector manipulation using STL algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a vector and I would like to multiply each of its elements with a scalar value. I wrote the following code for this

```
int func(const int x)
{
    return 10 * x; // say the scalar value is 10
}
void foo()
{
    // .. compute vector vert
    std::transform(vert.begin(), vert.end(), vert.begin(), ::func);
}
```

The code does the job, but I was wondering if there is a more concise implementation possible for this, one that does not require me to define the func function seperately

Comment: [Lambda is your friend.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b2b8cb813ce2114)

Comment: Does it have to use an algorithm? `for (int & x : vert) x *= 10;`

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Or even with c++1z: `for (x : vert) x *= 10;`

Comment: @Deduplicator, that did not work on Visual Studio 2013. Does x not need a type specification?

Comment: The official newest version is C++14. C++1z refers to the next one (in progress, target 2017). Clang has this specifc feature already.

Comment: @Deduplicator What's the point of that syntax? Does it default to an lvalue-reference?

Comment: @0x499602D2: The way I read it, making the most common and useful case nicer. It's equivalent to `for (auto&& x : vert) x *= 10;`.

Comment: @Deduplicator So this is only available for ranged-based fors?

Comment: Can someone tell me when to use std::transform and when to use std::for_each?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes. I mean, in other cases there would be ambiguity.

Comment: @user3670482 The first one if you want to transform an input-sequence into an output sequence, the second if you want to do something which each element of a sequence. So, if output- and input-sequence are identical, `std::for_each` is either more performant or at least no worse.

Comment: @Deduplicator, seems like the range based for syntax can be used in both cases instead. When to use transform/for_each as opposed to using some variant of range based for

Comment: I would use `transform` never and use a for-loop (or in some cases `for_each`) always, unless somebody can demonstrate a solid use-case for transform...

Comment: Probably it would be an interesting addition. Mr. STL thinks that "1.5-iterator-range" binary algorithms overloads are bad and it is a road to undefined behavior. He recommends using overloads with 2 ranges. See [CppCon 2014: Stephan Lavavej "STL Features And Implementation Techniques"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTeKf5Oek2c) (from 8:00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still have yet to see a case where `transform()` actually looks like a good answer... I would strongly suggest:

```
for (int& x : vert) {
    x *= 10; // or x = func(x)
}
```

It's clearer and more concise.